# one month after start date-joda

Tags: java, jodatime

I have to call a method that needs two parameters begin date and end date and my end date is exactly one month after the begin date. I used this:

```
mymethod(startDate.toDate(), startDate.plusMonths(1));
```

but I got this error:

```
the method mymethod(Date, Date) is not applicable for the arguments (Date, DateTime)
```

Any idea how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mymethod(startDate.toDate(), startDate.plusMonths(1));
```

should be:

```
mymethod(startDate.toDate(), startDate.plusMonths(1).toDate());
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot. I will accept your solution as soon as I get the permission.

Answer (score 1):

The method `mymethod()` seems to be declared with the datatypes Date as:

`mymethod(Date, Date)`

while the joda time method [plusMonths](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#plusMonths%28int%29) returns a value of type `DateTime`.

You can either change your method to work with `DateTime` or change the `DateTime` to `Date` after adding one month using the [toDate()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInstant.html#toDate%28%29) function.